# Как сделать проверку на повторяющиеся элементы словаря?

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
A = {
    "a": [1, 0, 0],  # уникален
    "b": [0, 1, 1],  # уникален
    "c": [1, 0, 1],  # уникален
    "d": [1, 1, 0],  # уникален
    "e": [1, 1, 1]   # уникален
}

B = {
    "a": [0, 0, 0],  # повторяется
    "b": [0, 0, 0],  # повторяется
    "c": [1, 0, 1],
    "d": [1, 1, 0],
    "e": [0, 1, 1]
}
```

Как сделать проверку на уникальность, при которой проверка словаря ***A*** будет ***True***, а ***B*** - ***False***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f(dict_):
    values = list(dict_.values())
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if values[i] in values[i + 1:]:
            return False
    return True
```